# How to get the file id of a google meet recording using google api?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-meet

This is what I am expecting

Create a calendar event with a google meet link - this is working

When the host records the meeting, it gets saved in the host's drive. We got the drive read permission using scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly

All I need is given the meeting id or calendar id, how to search for the respective recording files in the host's drive?

For example, something like:

```
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth: oauth2Client });
const res = await drive.files.list({
    q: "name contains '<meetingid or calender id>'",
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
});
```

I just want to get the recording file for given meeting. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are on the right track in using the drive.files.list. By default, all meeting recordings as well as meeting transcripts are saved and sent to the meeting organizer's Google drive under the `Meet Recordings` folder (given that the organizer has not changed the default settings). Also, by default, the names of these files are formatted as `[Meeting name] ([Date and time of meeting])`. Hence, in your query (q), you may want to place `"name contains '[Meeting Name]'"` and you can add `"and name contains '[Date of the meeting and time]'"` to even filter out the query.

Comment: Thought so, but just wanted to know if there is a direct relation between google meet id and recording in drive. Anyways this would work, thanks

Comment: I'm glad that helped. Let me compose an answer based on my comment. As for the relationship between Google Meet ID and the recording in Google drive, by default, when an event is created and is untitled, or if you have started an instant meeting (Google Meet > New Meeting > Start an instant meeting) the recording will have a default name based on the google meet id (i.e. the 10 digit meet id aaa-aaaa-aaa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion: Modify the Query Under drive.files.list Method

By default, all meeting recordings as well as meeting transcripts are saved and sent to the meeting organizer's Google drive under the `Meet Recordings` folder (given that the organizer has not changed the default settings). Also, by default, the file name of the recordings follow the format `[Title] ([Date and time of the meeting])`. However, there are two cases for the [Title]:

1. When the event or Google Meet has a title, the Google Meet recordings would have a [Title] `following the title of the event or Google Meet` (as shown below).

[image]

2. When the event or Google Meet has no title, the Google Meet recordings would have a [Title] `following the Google Meet ID` (as shown below).

[image]

With this, you may want to modify your query (q) under `drive.files.list` method to:

`"name contains '[Title]'"`

and you may further add the following to make the query more specific:

`"and name contains '[Date and time of the meeting]'"`

### References:

- [Record a Video Meeting](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/9308681)
- [Troubleshoot Recording Issues in Meetings](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/10619995)